# Axis of reflection in a mirror

Tags: visible-light, symmetry, reflection

When I look at my reflection in a planar mirror, the image I see is reflected about a vertical axis. Why is it this axis and not the horizontal axis?

Comment: Richard Feynman explains it best, as usual. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msN87y-iEx0

Comment: ***Reflections*** occur in a plane, not about an axis.